# Azure SQL BCP ASCII text file into one table column

Tags: sql-server, azure, bcp

I have pdf files converted to txt (ASCII).

I would like the entire text file(s) inserted into a table with 1 column (`varchar(max)`) in order to create a Fulltext-searchable index.

**I cannot figure out what parameters to use for row and field.**

```
Enter the file storage type of field RawData varchar(max): c
Enter prefix-length of field RawData [8]: 0
Enter length of field RawData [0]: 65,535
Enter field terminator [none]:
Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] y
Host filename [bcp.fmt]: MyImportFmt.fmt
Starting copy...
373 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 234    Average : (1594.02 rows per sec.)
```

Ive tried `\n` too.  This still imports into rows.  I will need to get this working and find a way to import all txt files in a file folder.  I would like to create an SSIS package to do this, but was told for azure one must use the bcp utility.  Please advise.  I saw a post re: creating SUBSTRING _INDEX function to select all the rows into another table column, which I can't get to work.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: I've tried to improve formatting and make the question itself more explicit.

Comment: Try `0x00` as row terminator (i.e. ASCII `NUL` character). Note that a format file can also specify a row terminator, it's possible you may have to omit the format file.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.